# How to add Benjamini-Hochberge corrected p value to boxplots, not the default 'holm'-corrected p value in R?

Tags: r

I plan to compare four groups of dataset using Kruskal Wallis test, do pairwise comparison and then using Benjamin-Hochberg to correct the p value. I have used `stat_compare_mean()` to show the global p value successfully, however, the p value resulted from pairwise comparison needed to be corrected using BH in my study whereas all the `p.adj` value in R seems to be 'holm'-corrected p value, according to this website (http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/).

I've tried stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparisons, aes(label = ..p.adj.. ), method = "wilcox.test", p.adjust.method = "BH").

Here are my full codes:

```r
comparisons <- lapply(as.data.frame(combn(Treatment, m =2 , simplify = TRUE)), function(pair) {
  as.character(pair)
}) 

for (metabolite in metabolites) {
  metabolite_dat_during <- setNames(subset(dat_P_BI_QUANT_during, select = c(metabolite, "Treatment")), nm = c("metabolite", "Treatment"))

  gg_during <- ggboxplot(metabolite_dat_during, x = "Treatment", y = "metabolite",title = metabolite, color = "Treatment", palette = "jco",
                         add = c("median_iqr", "jitter")) +
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = comparisons, aes(label = ..p.adj.. ), method = "wilcox.test", p.adjust.method = "BH")+ 
    stat_compare_means(label.y=0.0001) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name = "conc(mmol/L)")
  ggsave(filename = paste0(save_dir, "metabolite-", metabolite, ".png"), plot = gg_during)

}
```

I expected to the p value can be corrected using BH using my above code. However, p values seem not to be corrected, even not using 'holm' as the p values are the same as the uncorrected p value. Beside, I also encounter some errors:

> In wilcox.test.default(c(0.07, 0.07, 0.06, 0.08, 0.06,  ... : cannot compute exact p-value with ties.

Comment: Appears your various unspecified packages do not all talk to each other or don’t have the argument names you expect.  Your question, unfortunately, does not have any data or library calls.

Comment: Hi, I am using "ggpubr" here.